# Spring Boot - NoClassDefFoundError NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller$2
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller.add(NioBlockingSelector.java:251) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1221) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:378) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:347) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:561) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:77) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:499) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:375) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:345) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:405) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at com.domain.DownloadController.load(DownloadController.java:97) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/net/NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller$2
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar!/:8.5.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]


        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

I built my spring-boot application using mvn package. Whole application works fine, however when I'm trying to download large file sometimes I've got this spurious excpetion with NoClassDefFoud. The rest of application works fine, download of small files works fine too.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Why I get this exception when downloading large file and why this transitive Tomcat dependencies are not included via spring-boot-starter.

```
File file = rootLocation.resolve(fileName).toFile();
resp.setContentLength((int) file.length());
resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName));

OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = resp.getOutputStream();
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(uploadDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (out != null) {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {}
    }
}
```

Updated

Sometimes I've got another spurious excpetion like - `NoClassFefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/exceptionutils` Looke liks all this issues are related to hot-restart. Once I restarted the app they have gone

Comment: Do you have `tomcat-util` in your classpath?

Comment: Mentioned class is a part of tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar which is included as dependency spring-boot-starter-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have multiple versions of `tomcat-util` in your classpath.

Maven commands that can help you debugging this:

```
mvn dependency:tree
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are creating a war and deploying it to an external tomcat.Try changing your pom.xml entry to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This should do the trick as it will not use the embedded tomcat for jars

Comment: That actually worked ! I commented this line in gradle: 
`providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")`

Comment: Glad that it helped :)